# Ajax request causing Internal Server error

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

This is my ajax call which is causing internal server error

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          'completed': true
        },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
      });
```

But when i try manually with the django rest framework it is working fine.

Comment: What's the error trace from your server?

Comment: Show the block of code that's being hit by this Ajax call.